# Spinner's getSelectedItemPosition() method returns unexpected results

Tags: android, spinner

My app has a spinner with four entries in it. I need to be able to retrieve which of these labels is selected, not the actual labels themselves. Below is my partial code for doing this:

```
// Set up the activity's Spinner
    spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pay_periods, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.main_spinner_payperiod);
    s.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

In a later method:

```
switch(payPeriod.getSelectedItemPosition()){
    case(0): // Daily
        dailyAllowance = Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString());
    case(1): // Weekly
        dailyAllowance = (Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString())) / 7;
    case(2): // Bi-weekly
        dailyAllowance = (Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString())) / 14;
    case(3): // 30 days
        dailyAllowance = (Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString())) / 30;
    case(Spinner.INVALID_POSITION):
        dailyAllowance = 0;
    default:
        dailyAllowance = 42;    // Junk value, for debugging purposes
    }
```

This method always seems to return 42, no matter which of the Spinner's items I have selected. Can anyone help me figure out why? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `break` in your switch-case condition

```
switch(payPeriod.getSelectedItemPosition()) { 

    case(0): // Daily
        dailyAllowance = Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString());
    break;

    case(1): // Weekly
        dailyAllowance = (Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString())) / 7;
    break;

    case(2): // Bi-weekly
        dailyAllowance = (Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString())) / 14;
    break;

    case(3): // 30 days
        dailyAllowance = (Float.parseFloat(payment.getText().toString())) / 30;
    break;

    case(Spinner.INVALID_POSITION):
        dailyAllowance = 0;
    break;
    default:
        dailyAllowance = 42;    // Junk value, for debugging purposes
    break;
}
```

Omitting `break` in switch-case condition might give a wrong behavior. If a `case` (without `break`) was chosen the flow still continues and the `default` condition is always executed.

Comment: I've seen some successful uses of switch-case statements with breaks and some without. Can you explain why?

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I was still restricted from approving your answer. There you go!